# How to incorporate the probability of failure in transition

Tags: random, anylogic

I am new to AnyLogic. I have 20 equipment units in working state, and the probability of failure of an equipment unit during a disaster like a hurricane is 0.6. So, I want 12 (0.6*20) random equipment units to undergo state change from the 'Working' state to the 'Failed' state. How can I do this in AnyLogic?

I tried to use a conditional trigger with the condition randomTrue(0.6). But, I did not give the result I expected.